# Parsing text in java

Tags: java, io, file-handling

I am  new in high-level programming,
Well I know its very unprofession question:-

I like to Parse a file in java

e.g 
my in.vmf contains:

```
vaps graxxx
metagraphic  
ccccc cccc
vvvv vvvv
xxx cccc
Begin_object "xxx"
 Translate
 somethoing
 anything
end Begin_object
```

I would like to parse the above file with following rules:

- if it find a first line "vaps graxx" it will go copy/parse till it find Begin_object. and add some line
- then search for other word and copy/parse till something and add some line
- continue for other similar search and so on

here if my piece code

```
    BufferedReader FileBuf;

    try{

        // Open the file and read the file
        FileBuf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("arc.VMF"));


        // Create a new file 
        OutputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("newarc.VMF"));

        // Start reading file Line by Line 

        while ((LineRead = FileBuf.readLine()) != null) {

            // LineStr = LineRead.split("");

            if (LineRead.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Line is empty");

            }
            if ((LineRead.startsWith("%"))
                    && (LineRead.indexOf("V A P S") > 0)) {
                OutputFile.println(LineRead);
            }
            if (LineRead.indexOf("BEGIN_OBJECT") > 0) {
                    OutputFile.println(LineRead);

                }

.......
.....
....
            }

        FileBuf.close();
        OutputFile.close();
```

Can anyone give some advices on it , will be a great help.
Thanks

Comment: Also look at Regular Expression. It used for searching complex expressions in text. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to write a parser (in java or another language) by using something like jflex and cup.

By doing that, you can parse a file and specify extremely clear rules.

Take a look here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing

JFlex : http://jflex.de/

Cup : http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/CUP/manual.html

Comment: You have forgotten the most forgiving of them all! I mean [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), of course.

Comment: yes, but I don't know it well, I've used JFlex/Cup successfully so I can objectively and sincerely recommend it ;)

Comment: Thanks, But I need to use only Java

Comment: Well, JFlex, cup and ANTLR are coded in java. You want to say that you don't want to use external framework, ins't it ?

Comment: ya Exactly . this parsing code need to be embedded in some other project, so we don't much space for using other framework / tools.